# creating pop up window

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a pop-up window on button click. But, I'm getting error on getSupportFragmentManager();

```
public class PrizeList extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    TextView players, prizePoolList, perKill, rank1, rank2, rank3;
    SeekBar seekBar;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prize_list_layout, null);
        builder.setView(view).setTitle("Prize List")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

        players = view.findViewById(R.id.players);
        prizePoolList = view.findViewById(R.id.prizePoolList);
        perKill = view.findViewById(R.id.perKill);
        rank1 = view.findViewById(R.id.rank1);
        rank2 = view.findViewById(R.id.rank2);
        rank3 = view.findViewById(R.id.rank3);
        seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
holder.prizeList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "prize list clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    private void openDialog() {
        PrizeList prizeList = new PrizeList();
        prizeList.show(prizeList.requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Prize");
    }
```

The error I'm getting,

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.luteraa.luteraaesports, PID: 6355
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.BGMICategoryAdapter.openDialog(BGMICategoryAdapter.java:93)
at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.BGMICategoryAdapter.access$000(BGMICategoryAdapter.java:25)
at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.BGMICategoryAdapter$1.onClick(BGMICategoryAdapter.java:76)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7191)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7164)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27856)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)

Comment: Your `prizeList` Dialog is simply not bound to any `Activity`  so calling `geActivity()` on a fragment without parent activity will return `null`.

Comment: Then show me the solution please

Answer (score 0):

```
  DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,tasks,getSupportFragmentManager());
```

you can pass the parameter getSupportFragmentManager in
adapter
calling
and get the constructor in getSupportFragmentManager like this

```
    DataAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasklist, 
   FragmentManager 
   supportFragmentManager) {
    this.context = context;
    this.taskList = tasklist;
    this.supportFragmentManager=supportFragmentManager;
}
```

After pass the object supportFragmentManager in the prizeList
show
method

```
PrizeList prizeList = new PrizeList();
        prizeList.show(supportFragmentManager, "Prize List");
```

also work in my project so this help to solve your error in
supportFragmentManager